# Significance of a period in a time seiries

Tags: frequency

I have a time series sampled in days and when I plot the amplitude vs time it looks like the signal is oscialating at an annual frequency. The series is 15 years long.

Is there a test I can use to test the significance of this frequency in the data? Meaning, test what is the probablity the oscilation is random.

I have used fft and autocorrelation to validate the existence of the period but these tests don't give a probablity measure as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to determine whether or not your series is plain white noise. If that's the case, the [Ljung-Box test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ljung%E2%80%93Box_test) for autocorrelation should give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

To test the significance of the annual frequency, you need a probability model. As Digio pointed out, Ljung-Box test would work to test for the existence of autocorrelation in the ts. But it wouldn't be clear if that's the annual or seasonal pattern in the data.

I am sure there are many ways to approach this problem. But if I were you, I would build a model, e.g., ARMA with an annual trend, and see if the coefficient for that annual trend is significant or not. I could also use information criterion to compare two models, one with an annual trend, the other one without an annual trend.

Hope it helps.